# How does WASM get interpreted by the EOS virtual machine?

Tags: wasm

WASM is meant to be executed by general purpose computers. How does the low level WASM get converted to a form that the EOS virtual machine can understand?

Comment: Related https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-is-eos-wasm-virtual-machine-hardened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WASM is the form that the virtual machine understands.

Answer (score 4):

WebAssembly is indeed the instruction format that the virtual machine understands.

The actual interaction between the eos library and the wasm binary is done through [WebAssembly modules](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/blob/master/Modules.md). Every contract thus has to export an apply function, which serves as the entrypoint. It can also import functions to interact with the eos environment. A small subset of these functions are listed [here](https://github.com/eos-typescript/eos-assemblyscript-api/blob/20c0f0fa71f65a7b9826dc1c16eb8a54400b6219/src/eos_interface.ts).

Finally I'm pretty sure the eos virtual machine does not support the webassembly float types.

Comment: Not enough reputation to add a comment to @wanheda's so let me note it here: EOS WASM does support floating point though only through a software library so as to avoid inconsistencies between the different existing implementations.

Answer (score 1):

"EOS virtual machine" ==  WAVM or binaryen, which is a WASM-specific VM.

Comment: Please add some more details or resources.

Comment: here is https://github.com/go-interpreter/wagon, a standalone VM for interpreting WASM, which is easy to understand  compared to binaryen(https://github.com/WebAssembly/binaryen) or WAVM(https://github.com/AndrewScheidecker/WAVM).   You can see that wagon is a classic stack-based VM, who provides a stack, memory, and some instructions. Cause Wasm is well formed after compiling by AOT tools, When interpreting, A PC travels wasm bytecode,  get the operators and run the instructions(actually binding a function), get the result and push into the stack.

Comment: Until reaching the end of the bytecode, you can get the result.  Interpreting is simple compared to designing the syntax in some way.   I am not sure this is what you want to know.