# How is EOS WASM virtual machine hardened?

Tags: wasm, security

WASM, famous from web browsers, regularly sees breaking out of sandbox issues. For example, see WebAssembly notes here:

https://www.cisecurity.org/advisory/multiple-vulnerabilities-in-google-chrome-could-allow-for-arbitrary-code-execution_2018-043/

Often these issues may lead to arbitrary code execution, the most dangerous kind of issue. These are especially prone with just-in-time WASM code interpretation, as the attacker has a lot of control over produced binary code. In the case of EOS, this would be malicious smart contract code. Also, we have similar cases over the history of Java JVM that allowed executing sandboxed Java code to allow to escape into host OS.

Now 360 (Chinese Internet company) claims that they have found arbitrary code execution in EOS:

https://twitter.com/cnLedger/status/1001335269180653568

What safety measures, like process isolation, EOS takes to ensure that the future arbitrary code execution or sandbox escapes in WASM don't allow taking over the block producer?

Comment: Looks like 360 went out with a blog post http://blogs.360.cn/blog/eos-node-remote-code-execution-vulnerability/

Comment: More issues are known: https://thenextweb.com/hardfork/2018/06/05/hacker-eos-cryptocurrency/ (while in that article is a general misunderstanding whether the mainnet is live or not.)

Comment: Dan talked a bit about the vulnerabilities reported in that article https://twitter.com/rektkid_/status/1001496058592145408

Answer (score 3):

The [Web Assembly Website](https://webassembly.org/docs/security/) has information on the potential security issues for both users and developers when coding in WASM.

With regards to arbitrary code execution in EOS, @confused00 points out that [these bugs were fixed](https://twitter.com/rektkid_/status/1001496058592145408) before [the report](http://blogs.360.cn/post/eos-node-remote-code-execution-vulnerability.html) was even published.

EOS has a very quick turn around for serious bugs. If a vulnerability is found it can be fixed very quickly, as has already happened recently with [the RAM problem](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/is-there-a-flaw-in-deciding-who-can-pay-for-ram).

Answer (score 0):

EOS 2.0 adds a protection mechanism via CPU/OS paging, as stated in this article:

https://medium.com/eosio/eos-virtual-machine-a-high-performance-blockchain-webassembly-interpreter-75224d4779d5

There are no details available yet, but it seems that sandboxes VM processes get their own memory space and can't get out of it.